# treating a subdirectory like a web root directory in xampp

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, xampp, hosts-file

I am running Xampp on a Windows 7 machine. I have a website that is running off a directory in my web root. I access the website by going to `http://localhost/foobar`.

I would like to set it up so that I can point my local browser to say, `http://foobar`, and have it treat the foobar directory like the web root directory.

Is that a matter of changing the hosts file or configuration on apache?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get your browser to look for `http://foobar` on your local machine you'll have to add this line to your host file

```
127.0.0.1 foobar
```

Then add a virtual host in your Apache http.conf file,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot path/to/foobar
    ServerName foobar
</VirtualHost>
```

You may also have to add another virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot path/to
    ServerName localhost
ServerAlias 127.0.0.*
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks, Musa, that worked great! The ServerAlias part was not necessary.

Comment: Some additional info, with xampp the http.conf included the file httpd-vhosts.conf, which is where I made my changes. I also had to uncomment the line NameVirtualHost *:80 to get it to work.

Comment: I get: Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

Comment: @Talon Make sure Apache (or whatever server you are using) has access to the directory. For example, storing the data in your user directory  C:\users\... might be problematic.